# PDF not downloading when file is called

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have a database that is storing all my pdf files for a website. The table has columns for the library_item_id, filename(name of the file), mime_type, File size, file_item(the Blob) and I have a php file called download.php. This file is supposed to download the correct file from the database when they user clicks the link. But when the file is downloaded and clicked to open I get Adobe saying it cannot open the pdf. Saying its not decoded correctly. Here is my download.php file:

```
require_once("scripts/connection.php");
    if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $fid = $_GET["id"];
    }
    else{
        header("Location: literature.php"); 
    }

    $sql= "SELECT filename, mime_type, file_item FROM library_items WHERE library_item_id = ?"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $fid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($filename, $mime, $file_item);

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $file_name = $filename;
        $mime_type = $mime;
        $file = $file_item; 
    }

    header("Content-length: ".strlen($file));
    header("Content-type: $mime_type");
    header("Content-disposition: download; filename=$file_name"); 
    echo $file;

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

I have tried everything I could think of including add the obj_flush() commands and all that it still gives me the same error. What am I doing wrong on this?

Here is the edit for the code inserting the file into the database.

```
session_start();

    $display = trim($_POST["file-display-name"]);
    $company = trim($_POST["companies"]);
    $lib_cat = trim($_POST["library-cats"]);

    if(empty($display) || empty($company) || empty($lib_cat)){
        $_SESSION["errormsg"] = "Required information is missing please fill out all required fields.";
        header("Location: ../library.php");
    }
    else{
        $file_name = $_FILES['library-file']['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['library-file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['library-file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['library-file']['type'];

        $fp = fopen($tmp_name, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmp_name));
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $file_name = addslashes($file_name);    
        }

        if(empty($content)){
            $_SESSION["errormsg"] = "Required information is missing please fill out all required fields.";
            header("Location: ../library.php"); 
        }
        else{   
            require_once("connection.php");

            // Insert the logo into the companies photo table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO library_items(filename, mime_type, file_size, file_item, display_name, company_id, library_category_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $file_name, $file_type, $file_size, $content, $display, $company, $lib_cat);
            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                $_SESSION["errormsg"] = "Failed to add library item: ".mysqli_error();
                header("Location: ../library.php");
            }
        }
        unset($_SESSION["errormsg"]);

        $_SESSION["successmsg"] = "Library Item successfully added into the database.";
        header("Location: ../library.php");
    }
```

UPDATE:
I now have the file downloading and attempting to display once the downloaded file is double clicked to open. It is telling me there is an invalid colorSpace. From what I can tell this is a problem when the file is uploaded into the database. From my upload file posted is there anything I am not doing correctly?

Comment: What is your table structure? It seems that you have the wrong type for the file_item column.

Comment: @Alex : Do you need download?

Comment: file_item is a large blob. This is actually the content of the file.

Comment: And yes I need the file to download or display on the page one or the other.

Comment: @AlexBeyer : Try my edited answer. Sorry, I didn't tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following changes. In the insert file
Instead of

`$content = addslashes($content);`

use

`$content = base64_encode($content);`

So while downloading, decode it.

`$file =  base64_decode($file_item);`

Replace the following code

```
header("Content-type: '".$mime_type."'");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='".$file_name."'");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($file);
```

with

```
header("Content-length: ".strlen($file));
header("Content-type: $mime_type");
header("Content-disposition: download; filename=$file_name"); 
echo $file;
```

Comment: If I use this it doesnt give me the cannot load pdf but the file opens and its literally a blank rectangle like the pdf is created but nothing was added to it. :/

Comment: If i try and open it open from the file thats downloaded it also tells me that it has an invalid colorSpace? I have never seen this before.

Comment: Is the problem where I am uploading the file into the database? From what I have found on this error is that it has to do with the file not being saved correctly but I cannot see where I went wrong the upload of the file to the database.

Comment: Use `base64_encode` instead of `addslashes` @AlexBeyer

Comment: Sweet that was the problem! thanks I forgot all about the encode.

Answer (score 0):

check if size of downloaded file is correct (matches size of file in database). If it is, you should be debugging the part where the file is inserted into database. If not - check if anything gets printed out before sending file to browser - maybe `scripts/connection.php` prints something like empty line, error message or BOM? 
If you can't find it, try turning output buffering on and call `ob_clean()` before sending file.

Sorry for my english, I hope it's understandable.

Comment: I look at this there shouldnt be anything being printed out. I will post my insert code as an edit also.

Comment: Sorry, I was totally wrong. You can't use readfile with string, as it is not a file. use `echo` instead.